# Getting Random color using Random Class?

Tags: java, android

My app's requirement is a light but not transparent color for the listview items. I am getting random colors, but it is very dark oftenly. And I don't know in which range can I get light colors only. The range given randomly is like this:

```
 Random rndm = new Random();
 int color = Color.argb(255, rndm.nextInt(256), rndm.nextInt(256), rndm.nextInt(256));
 RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.front);
 rl.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: If you have generated a Bitmap, Palette should be a solution: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: I didn't generate Bitmap as you can see i am just setting backgroudnColor to relative layout.

Comment: You could... it's just an idea. See my answer and try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want lighter colors. This means the RGB components values must be between 128 and to 255.

Since `Random.nextInt(int max)` returns an int `between 0 inclusive and max exclusive`, you may want to try something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.nextInt(128) + 128; // 128 ... 255
int g = rnd.nextInt(128) + 128; // 128 ... 255
int b = rnd.nextInt(128) + 128; // 128 ... 255

Color clr = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
```

Comment: Indeed lighter colors will be included between 128 and 255 (just to explain).

Comment: your approach returns what i wanted, returning me 2296164,5335561 and 8141674 while Bowsska's returning 12958379,10361308,11232046. these result for three items. Thank you alot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079204/how-to-done-http-calls-in-background-using-timer

Comment: It seems you already got your answer. By the way, it is not a good idea to attention a specific user for every question you post. I don't have all the answers. This one, in particular - I could not answer to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format? but this you can please.

Comment: No, Devendra. Until now, I never had anything to do with POST  REST, JSON, etc. It's really an unknown field for me, at the moment being.

Comment: @DerGolem Sir, I want to make UI like this [APP's HOMEPAGE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaleshark.retailmenot&hl=en) I am not able to post answer and it is not meets to standards i think. I just wanted to make this app's homepage. the scrolling effect. please guide me. its really emergency.

Comment: Post a new question, with the desired UI. What you get instead of it. Some code to show some effort and the code where are you stuck at. Clearly explain what bugs you and why you can't go on.

Answer (score 4):

I was pointing an idea to you, which I'll explain here:

```
Random random = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(context);
bitmap.eraseColor(color);

Palette.from(bitmap).getLightVibrantColor();
```

See? I'm creating a dummy `Bitmap`, fill it with your randomly generated color, then using `Palette` API to get a "light vibrant" color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format? @shkschneider

Answer (score 4):

Generally you need one of the RGB values being are greater than 128 for getting a bright color, so picking up 3 random values, and checking for one to be greater than 128 could be enough. The greater the value, the brighter it will be.

You can check for the average to be greater than 128, it can bring a good result.

```
public int getRandomColor() {

Random rndm = new Random();

int r = rndm.nextInt(256);
int g = rndm.nextInt(256);
int b = rndm.nextInt(256);
int adjust = 0;

if( (r + g + b)/3 < 128)
    int adjust = (128 - (r + g + b)/3)/3;

r += adjust;
g += adjust;
b += adjust;

return Color.argb(255, r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Der golem approach returning me 2296164,5335561 and 8141674 while your returning 12958379,10361308,11232046. these result for three items. @Bowsska. Thank you alot.

Answer (score 3):

To get a random color which is bright, you'll want to each channel to have some minimum value.

Here's the code:

```
// minimumBrightnessRatio between 0 and 1. 1 = all white, 0 = any possible color. Best results would be 0.5.
public int getRandomColor(float minimumBrightnessRatio)
{
    Random rndm = new Random();

    final int minimumColorValue = (int)(255f * minimumBrightnessRatio);
    final int variableColorValue = 255 - minimumColorValue;

    final int r = minimumColorValue + rndm.nextInt(variableColorValue);
    final int g = minimumColorValue + rndm.nextInt(variableColorValue);
    final int b = minimumColorValue + rndm.nextInt(variableColorValue);

    return Color.argb(255, r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I want to make UI like this [APP's HOMEPAGE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaleshark.retailmenot&hl=en) I am not able to post answer and it is not meets to standards i think. I just wanted to make this app's homepage. the scrolling effect. please guide me. its really emergency.

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the color space you're choosing from. Right now you're using the whole RGB spectrum and half of that is dark colors of course. So I suggest you're setting a baseline color range for all channels (by experimentation or by looking at your favourite graphics program's color picker) and just randomize the range above that baseline.

```
final int basec = 128; //baseline would be 50% gray

Random rndm = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, basec + rndm.nextInt(256-basec), basec + rndm.nextInt(256-basec), basec + rndm.nextInt(256-basec));

RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.front);
rl.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with intensity of light(in your case, you need light colors), `HSI model` comes in handy. You can randomly generated the Intensity between 0.8 to 1 and randomize Hue and Saturation. Then convert it to RGB.